# Symfony controller alternate redirect

Tags: symfony, redirect, controller, dashboard

My Symfony project uses the standard routes to access forms/content generated by the specific controller attached to the specified route.

However, I'm trying to create a configuration dashboard which will import content, mostly forms, from other routes and for display on a single page. Using services, I am able to call and retrieve data from controllers in neighbouring bundles.

So far my dashboard system works as does the native route of the individual forms that I'm importing to the dashboard.

What I'm struggling with is how to redirect to the dashboard when I edit and submit any of the forms instead of redirecting to it's native route/page.

I've been using code below :

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $raw=false, $id=3){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $item = $em->getRepository('StockBundle:Stock')->find($id);

        if(!$item)
            return;

        $stockform = $this->createForm(new StockType(), $item,
            array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('stock_edit', array('id'=>$id)),
                'method' => 'PUT'
            )
        )
        //->add('raw', 'true')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label'=>'Update'))
        ->handleRequest($request);

        if($stockform->isValid()){
            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();
          
            if($raw)
                return $this->redirect($this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer'));
            else
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('stock_list'));
        }

        /*******************
         * data to return based on source of request
         ************************/
        if($raw)
            return $stockform->createView();
        else
            return $this->render('StockBundle:StockController:edit.html.twig', array(
                'stockform' => $stockform->createView(),
            ));
    }
```

My code above is a controller which generates a form and also acts as the destination when the form is submitted. The **$raw** argument is my technique for determining if I want to return only the form data or the full Twig generated markup.

That works fine because the action is exposed as a service and I can call the action as a function call passing the necessary arguments.

**However, when the form is submitted, my $raw argument is not part of the submitted data which means there is nothing that can be tested to determine which route to redirect to.**

I tried adding a field to the form using `->add('raw', 'true')` but I get the following error:

```
Could not load type "true"
```

How can I pass my "raw" boolean value so I can access it when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Try detecting the request method to determine what to do.

E.g.:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
    //do form submit stuff
}
else
{
    //do normal stuff
}
```